# In Typescript, is there any way to typecheck passed-in JSX.Element's?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

Consider this simple case:

Client of library:

```
class ClientComponent extends React.Component<any,any> {
    render() {
        const myNestedElement = (<LibNestedComponent/>)
        return <LibComponent nested={myNestedElement}/> 
    }
}
```

Library:

```
class LibNestedComponent extends React.Component<any,any> {
    render() { return <div>nested stuff</div> }
}

interface LibComponentProps { nested: JSX.Element }
class LibComponent  extends React.Component<LibComponentProps,any> {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.nested}</div>
    }
}
```

As the author of Lib, I'd like to be able to tell my `LibComponent` clients, via the `LibComponentProps` interface, that the passed-in `nested` prop must be an element of type `LibNestedComponent` - not just any old j.random element.  But AFAICT, there's no way to do this; the [Typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) even says:

> **The JSX result type.**  By default the result of a JSX expression is typed as any. You can customize the type by specifying the `JSX.Element`
>   interface. However, it is not possible to retrieve type information
>   about the element, attributes or children of the JSX from this
>   interface. It is a black box.

*Does anyone have a workaround that achieves this kind of typechecking without too much pain?*

(The example is deliberately trivial and is not meant to be a sensible use-case.)

Comment: I've seen a few questions regarding a type-based way to restrict parent/child components but as far as I'm aware, there isn't one.

Comment: For any element, you can assign type as `React.ReactElement<LibComponentProps>`, which will restrict the passed in nested prop to be one of `LibComponentProps`.

Comment: @HardikModha I'm not sure how you mean to use `ReactElement`, but AFAICT that's either incorrect, unenforced, or not on point.  Can you show what you mean?

Comment: From the type definitions of the [`react`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/index.d.ts#L2693) you can see that `JSX.Element` extends the interface `ReactElement`. So may be, you can use `React.ReactElement<P>` instead of `JSX.Element`. As you can pass a type interface as a generic parameter, it will restrict the prop to be one of the types you provided. But still not sure this is what you want.

Comment: @HardikModha That doesn't constrain the kind of element - only its parameters.  Still, better than nothing!  I mistakenly thought it wasn't being enforced, but found a `[name: string]: any` in a props interface ancestor, which opened the barn door for anything at all.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, It won't constraint the kind of element.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from my comment, I don't know if there is a typescript way to restrict the type of component that client component can pass. But there is a way through which you can determine the type of component that was passed as a prop.

You can check the name of the component which was passed and see which type is it.

```
if (this.props.nested.type.name === 'LibNestedComponent') {
   console.log('A valid component is passed');
} else {
   console.log('Invalid component is passed');
}
```

where `nested` is the component you passed in the example you provided.

In the below picture you can see the name of the component.

[image]

But again, this would be a run-time detection.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the type of `this.props.nested` using the object

```
if (this.props.nested.type !== LibNestedComponent) {
   throw new Error('Invalid prop passed. Make sure that an instance of LibNestedComponent is passed through the nested prop')
}
```

The problem with Hardik's answer is that, in case your code gets minified, the value of `type.name` will change and your code will fail. So you should go for the `type` property directly instead.

Comment: Thanks... I was trying to find a compile-time validation though!