# Typescript Type to accept a React component type with subset of Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, type-conversion

There is a component **Button** with following props:

```
ButtonProps = {
  variant: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'tertiary';
  label: string;
  // a few more props like onChange, size etc.
}
```

Now, I want to create another component called "ButtonGroup" component that accepts a Button instance as a prop but can only accept primary or secondary variant.
How can I enforce that?

ButtonGroup component looks this:

```
 <ButtonGroup 
    primaryButton={<Button variant="primary">Submit</Button>}
    otherButton={<Button variant="secondary">Cancel</Button>}
   />
```

Now, the props for **ButtonGroup** are as follwos:

```
type PrimaryButtonProps = Omit<ButtonProps, 'variant'> & {
  variant: 'primary' | 'secondary';
};

type ButtonGroupProps = BaseComponentProps<'div'> & {
    size?: 'small' | 'medium';
    primaryButton: React.ReactElement<PrimaryButtonProps, typeof Button>;
    otherButton?: React.ReactElement<OtherButtonProps, typeof Button>;
  };
```

I expect primaryButton to be a Button instance will all Button props but restricting variant to be either primary or secondary. But, with this current implementation, typescript doesn't complain if I provide a tertiary variant too.

```
 <ButtonGroup 
    primaryButton={<Button variant="tertiary">Submit</Button>} // TS SHOULD COMPLAIN BUT IT DOES NOT
   />
```

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42955400/4980215

Comment: Would it be acceptable to just take in the primary button props and render the Button inside the ButtonGroup?

Comment: This is a problem due to React, not Typescript. Check out this Playground where the type inference works fine and properly allows me to do what you're trying to do to above: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBARgrsYB7AdgNQIYCcCWGXADOUAvFAN4BQUUAbtngQFxQDkYuAttiK1AD5tCEAMaoAJjz6DWwCFmB4svalAA2GGBDUtCwXCgDmlAL6VKoSFA45uygEIJkKAApYkYYmQDynHMAAeeERUTFx8IgAaNnpwglYAPigAMgpVWMZgFnYuKQEhUQkpU3MxFD0oYTLJZRZg5zDMrwoMiOy5BSVeaI0tHTY5PVYzSjKKjBYbOxBHENd3T1IWhjaB+UUpHs1tdoghkbHgWEnchydUNw9m8lbmNinN9W3+2T3gYaA

I'd also go with what @adrisons is suggesting, it makes more sense any way.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the cleanest solution would be to separate the implementation of each component to enforce its specific types.

```js
interface ButtonProps {
  variant: "primary" | "secondary" | "tertiary";
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const Button = ({ variant, children }: ButtonProps): React.ReactElement => (
  <button>{children}</button> // apply styles based on the variant
);

interface PrimaryButtonProps {
  label: string;
  variant: "primary" | "secondary";
}

const PrimaryButton = ({ label, variant }: PrimaryButtonProps) => (
  <Button variant={{ variant }}>{{ label }}</Button>
);
```

So, when you create a ButtonGroup, you should pass the specific PrimaryButton type, instead the generic one

```js
type ButtonGroupProps = BaseComponentProps<'div'> & {
    size?: 'small' | 'medium';
    primaryButton: React.ReactElement<PrimaryButtonProps, typeof PrimaryButton>;
    // ...
  };

<ButtonGroup 
    primaryButton={<PrimaryButton variant="tertiary">Submit</PrimaryButton>} // TS should complain here
   />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PrimaryButton** component instead of **Button** and it will highlight the variant other than *primary* or *secondary*.

Checkout the working CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-bxwm95).

```js
interface ButtonProps {
  variant: "primary" | "secondary" | "tertiary";
  label: string;
}

function Button({ variant, label }: ButtonProps) {
  return (
    <button style={{ color: variant === "primary" ? "blue" : "red" }}>
      {label}
    </button>
  );
}

type PrimaryButtonProps = Omit<ButtonProps, "variant"> & {
  variant: "primary" | "secondary";
};

interface ButtonGroupProps {
  primaryButton: React.ReactElement<PrimaryButtonProps>;
}

function ButtonGroup({ primaryButton }: ButtonGroupProps) {
  return <div>{primaryButton}</div>;
}

// See below type assertion. It's a hack but it works :)
const PrimaryButton = Button as (props: PrimaryButtonProps) => JSX.Element;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ButtonGroup
        primaryButton={<PrimaryButton variant="tertiary" label="Primary" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```